# How can I rebase from a remote tag onto local master

Tags: git, git-rebase

I cloned an open source third-party repository and started working locally, committing to local master.

The remote github repository now has a tag called 8.1.1

Whats the best way to rebase from that remote tag? I want to pull in the latest changes from that release only and then replay my changes on top.

I've done a `git checkout tags/8.1.1` but am now in a detached HEAD state

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While being on that `detached head` pointing to `tags/8.1.1`, create a (local) *branch* at that very place, for example `ver_8_1_1`. Then switch to your (local) master and do a normal rebase onto that branch.

```
git checkout tags/8.1.1    # you are here
git branch ver_8_1_1
git checkout master
git rebase -i ver_8_1_1
```

Or if you don't want to go around like that, check your *commit hash* of that detached head (== commit hash of the 811 tag) and then do a rebase onto that directly.

```
git checkout tags/8.1.1    # you are here, at commit #aabb11223344
git checkout master        # ignore your checkout completely
git rebase -i aabb11223344  # just like that
```

Comment: this link about [git-rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) adds some value to the answer through images and a little bit of details regarding `git rebase`.